# Dealing with edges of data for GeoServer LineSymbolizer

Tags: geoserver

I am creating contour lines of the ocean using the [GEBCO gridded bathy data](https://www.gebco.net/data_and_products/gridded_bathymetry_data/) tiff and a [SDL style](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/index.html) with [LineSymbolizer](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/reference/linesymbolizer.html). All looks good apart from at the edge of the data where the contour lines close at the edges. Is there a way to get LineSymbolizer (and TextSymbolizer) not to render the isolines on the edge of the data?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld"
  xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <NamedLayer>
    <Name>contour_dem</Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Bathymetry Contours</Title>
      <Abstract>Bathymetry contours produced from the GEBCO 15 arc-second gridded bathymetry</Abstract>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Transformation>
          <ogc:Function name="ras:Contour">
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>data</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
            <ogc:Function name="parameter">
              <ogc:Literal>levels</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>0</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-100</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-200</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-300</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-400</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-500</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-600</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-700</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-800</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-900</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-1000</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-1100</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-1200</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-1300</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-1400</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-1500</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-1600</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-1700</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-1800</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-1900</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-2000</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-3000</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-4000</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-5000</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-6000</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-7000</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-8000</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-9000</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-10000</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-11000</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>-12000</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:Function>
          </ogc:Function>
        </Transformation>
        ...
        <Rule>
          <Name>low</Name>
          <Title>Low Res Contours</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:Or>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>-1000</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
                <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
                <ogc:Literal>-6000</ogc:Literal>
              </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
            </ogc:Or>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <LineSymbolizer>
            <Stroke>
              <CssParameter name="stroke">#000000</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="stroke-width">1</CssParameter>
            </Stroke>
          </LineSymbolizer>
          <TextSymbolizer>
            <Label>
              <ogc:PropertyName>value</ogc:PropertyName>
            </Label>
            <Font>
              <CssParameter name="font-family">Arial</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-style">Normal</CssParameter>
              <CssParameter name="font-size">10</CssParameter>
            </Font>
            <LabelPlacement>
              <LinePlacement/>
            </LabelPlacement>
            <Halo>
              <Radius>
                <ogc:Literal>2</ogc:Literal>
              </Radius>
              <Fill>
                <CssParameter name="fill">#FFFFFF</CssParameter>
                <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">0.6</CssParameter>
              </Fill>
            </Halo>
            <Fill>
              <CssParameter name="fill">#000000</CssParameter>
            </Fill>
            <Priority>2000</Priority>
            <VendorOption name="followLine">true</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="repeat">100</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="maxDisplacement">50</VendorOption>
            <VendorOption name="maxAngleDelta">30</VendorOption>
          </TextSymbolizer>
        </Rule>
      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```